# Can my library code identify which project is currently accessing it?

Tags: .net, debugging, logging

I'm writing a logging/debugging library, and it would be useful if the library could dynamically figure out and report on which projects/libraries are calling into it.

Can I identify who is calling a given function in my library (say, if I call Log("blah") from both a web application and a windows system service, can the Log function figure out where it was called from)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()` will tell you which assembly called your logging library.

Comment: This seems limited to one-layer-deep calls, but worked for me. Thanks!